# Matlab while looping; a function within a function

Tags: matlab

How do i loop a function inside another function until both sides equal each other ?

for example

after I find this "f"

```
f = (1/(-1.8*log(((epsilon/D)/3.7)^2 + 6.9/Re)))^2;
```

I want to use that value of f and input it here

```
f = (1/ -2.0*log((epsilon/D) + (2.51/Re*sqrt(***f***))))^2
```

the program is supposed to loop until both sides equal each other or are relatively close. the acceptable accuracy or error is `0.00001`.

and how do I display that value of f that gives mme wha

Comment: You might want to use the [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) to calculate the friction factor. There are also [plenty of matlab scripts available](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=friction+factor+newtons+method+matlab&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#hl=en&safe=off&client=ubuntu&hs=f4S&channel=fs&sclient=psy-ab&q=newtons+method+matlab&oq=newtons+method+matlab&gs_l=serp.3..0i10l4.1466.2122.0.2294.7.5.0.0.0.0.270.974.0j4j1.5.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.clmzdFBfmUY&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&fp=a51e123fa64cea55&biw=1360&bih=537) on a cursory google search.

Comment: Does this [Moody chart pressure drop calculator](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/237-pressuredrop/content/pressure_drop/moody.m) help? `;)`

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you are trying to solve an expression

```
f = somefun(f);
```

where the initial value for f is given by

```
f = (1/(-1.8*log(((epsilon/D)/3.7)^2 + 6.9/Re)))^2
```

Your best bet (if it's available to you) is to use Matlab's optimization toolbox, where you set the function to be minimized to

```
f - somefun(f)
```

and where you can set the tolerance using `optimset('TolFun', 1e-5);`

If you don't have the toolbox, then drN's suggestion in the comments of using Newton's method is probably as good as any -and you will learn more from doing it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that's fix point iteration you are attempting to use there, with your first code line being a starting estimate and your second code line being the actual fixed point iteration.

In this case you need to simply repeat that second statement while testing the difference between successive iterations. Something like this for example.

```
f = 1;
df = 1;

while abs(df) > 0.0001
  fnew = log(20/f);
  df = fnew - f;
  f = fnew;
end;
```

BTW. The above is a simple example of fixed point iteration to solve f*exp(f)=20,  [or equivalently f = ln(20/f)]. Apply the same logic to your particular equation for "f", but beware that not all equations are amenable to fixed point iteration.